# Reference issue in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Hope I can explain this reasonably well. I'm having a problem where I'm iterating through an object and calling a function based on the parameters of each of the sub-objects, then overwriting some of the values of the returned object and then stuffing it into a master array that itself will be iterated through to create on-screen objects.

It's a scenario infrastructure, where I instance a scenario switchboard class and then call its methods to figure out what ships I need for this scenario, then I pull "blank" examples of each of the ship classes required, set some of their values to be correct for this scenario, then feed them into the process that creates the real game objects.

This is the basic scenario loading process:

```
//instance scenario loader class
        var scenarioMasterObj:LOB_Scenario_Data = new LOB_Scenario_Data();

        //first grab the scenario settings object which has all of the data like short description, long description, date battle occured, balance, basically everything but the ship OOBs
        //this data will be used to render the scenario selection screen and post-battle results screen. We just pass the scenario number
        var scenarioSettigs:Object = scenarioMasterObj.getScenarioSettings(1);

        //there are two side-specific OOBs (Orders of Battle, lists of ships for the scenario) to load
        for (var OOBToggle:int = 1; OOBToggle < 3; OOBToggle++) {

            var currentOOB:Object = new Object();

            if (1 == OOBToggle) {

                currentOOB = scenarioMasterObj.getScenarioSideOOB(1, 1);
            }

            else {

                currentOOB = scenarioMasterObj.getScenarioSideOOB(1, 2);
            }

            //specific ship objects we'll need
            var currentOOBShip:Object = new Object();
            var finalOOBShip:Object = new Object();

            //iterate through the current OOB to create the list of ships used in ship creation for side 1 or 2
            for each (var currentOOBShip:Object in currentOOB) {

                //pull final ship data based on shipClass and country properties of the OOB ships
                finalOOBShip = scenarioMasterObj.getShip(currentOOBShip.shipClass, currentOOBShip.country);

                //set scenario-specific values copying from the ship in the scenario OOB object
                finalOOBShip.name = currentOOBShip.name;
                finalOOBShip.sailState = currentOOBShip.sailState;
                finalOOBShip.shotType = currentOOBShip.shotType;
                finalOOBShip.crewQuality = currentOOBShip.crewQuality;
                finalOOBShip.column = currentOOBShip.column;
                finalOOBShip.row = currentOOBShip.row;
                finalOOBShip.column2 = currentOOBShip.column2;
                finalOOBShip.row2 = currentOOBShip.row2;
                finalOOBShip.direction = currentOOBShip.direction;

                //push to the array that will be iterated through to create the on-screen ship objects
                if (1 == OOBToggle) {

                    shipDataSide1.push(finalOOBShip);
                }

                else {

                    shipDataSide2.push(finalOOBShip);
                }
            }
        }
```

The currentOOB object looks like:

```
public function getOOB(side:int):Object {

        var return_Scen_OOB:Object = new Object();

        if (1 == side) {

            return_Scen_OOB = {

                Ship1: {shipClass: "GB_90_N", name: "London", country: "GB", column: 7, row: 7, column2: 7, row2: 8, direction: 4, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Crack"},
                Ship2: {shipClass: "GB_74A_N", name: "Impetueux", country: "GB", column: 7, row: 9, column2: 7, row2: 10, direction: 4, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Crack"},
                Ship3: {shipClass: "GB_74A_N", name: "Courageux", country: "GB", column: 7, row: 11, column2: 7, row2: 12, direction: 4, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Average"},
                Ship4: {shipClass: "GB_74B_N", name: "Captain", country: "GB", column: 1, row: 1, column2: 1, row2: 1, direction: 1, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Elite"},
                Ship5: {shipClass: "GB_38_N", name: "Indefatigable", country: "GB", column: 7, row: 15, column2: 7, row2: 16, direction: 4, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Crack"},
                Ship2: {shipClass: "GB_38_N", name: "Amelia", country: "GB", column: 1, row: 1, column2: 1, row2: 1, direction: 1, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Average"},

                Ship6: {shipClass: "GB_36A_N", name: "Amethyst", country: "GB", column: 1, row: 1, column2: 1, row2: 1, direction: 1, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Crack"},
                Ship7: {shipClass: "GB_32B_N", name: "Stag", country: "GB", column: 1, row: 1, column2: 1, row2: 1, direction: 1, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Crack"},
                Ship8: {shipClass: "GB_28_N", name: "Brilliant", country: "GB", column: 1, row: 1, column2: 1, row2: 1, direction: 1, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Average"},

                Ship9: {shipClass: "GB_18_N", name: "Cynthia", country: "GB", column: 7, row: 7, column2: 7, row2: 8, direction: 4, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Crack"},
                Ship10: {shipClass: "GB_18_N", name: "Saint Vincent", country: "GB", column: 25, row: 30, column2: 25, row2: 31, direction: 4, sailState: "battle", shotType: "round", crewQuality: "Crack"}
            }                   
        }
```

This is the call where it pulls the "blank" ship - an object that has the vast majority of the properties for that given ship class already set, and the OOB object includes the scenario-specific values we'll add to that blank ship. That looks like:

```
//After receiving the list of ships from getScenarioSideOOB(), game iterates through those lists calling this function to set up the game's master ship side arrays
    public function getShip(shipClass:String, shipCountry:String) {

        var returnShip:Object = new Object();

        //bummer here is we have to know what classes exist, so if any are added code must change here as well
        switch(shipCountry) {
            case "GB":

                switch(shipClass) {

                    case "GB_120_N":

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_120_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_110_N":

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_110_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_100_N":

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_100_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_98_N":

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_98_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_90_N":

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_90_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_80_N":

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_80_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_74A_N":

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_74A_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_74B_N":

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_74B_N;
                        break;
```

So I switch first on country and then on the passed-in shipClass string to return a specific "blank" ship object.

The problem is here:

```
//pull final ship data based on shipClass and country properties of the OOB ships
                finalOOBShip = scenarioMasterObj.getShip(currentOOBShip.shipClass, currentOOBShip.country);
```

If you'll notice in the OOB object, there is more than one ship of identical shipClass value. There are two with the class "GB_74A_N" and two with the class "GB_18_N". The second time the above function is called with the exact same parameters (e.g., shipCountry == "GB" and shipClass == "GB_74A_N") what is returned is not a new blank ship but a reference to the previous example.

And when I do the overrides to set this ship example to its correct values, the previous example in shipDataSide1 or shipDataSide2 are also overwritten:

```
//set scenario-specific values copying from the ship in the scenario OOB object
                finalOOBShip.name = currentOOBShip.name;
                finalOOBShip.sailState = currentOOBShip.sailState;
                finalOOBShip.shotType = currentOOBShip.shotType;
                finalOOBShip.crewQuality = currentOOBShip.crewQuality;
                finalOOBShip.column = currentOOBShip.column;
                finalOOBShip.row = currentOOBShip.row;
                finalOOBShip.column2 = currentOOBShip.column2;
                finalOOBShip.row2 = currentOOBShip.row2;
                finalOOBShip.direction = currentOOBShip.direction;
```

So if the OOB object hast two ship objects with the same shipClass, in the end the the shipDataSide1 or shipDataSide2 arrays end up with one of them missing and two copies of the other, which confuses the code later in trying to draw them onscreen.

So what am I doing wrong here? How do I make sure each time I call scenarioMasterObj.getShip(currentOOBShip.shipClass, currentOOBShip.country) that the return is a "fresh" object and not a reference to an existing object? Took quite a while debugging to figure out what was going on, and I've spent a couple hours experimenting trying to get around this without ridiculous brute force methods but not having any luck. Help would be much appreciated.

=========================== UPDATE ============================

I have fixed the problem, but as noted it seems very brute force and there has to be a more elegant way to make it work. Basically I'm reinstancing the object from which we pull the "blank" ships, so each returned ship has nothing to do reference-wise to any previously returned one.

```
//After receiving the list of ships from getScenarioSideOOB(), game iterates through those lists calling this function to set up the game's master ship side arrays
    public function getShip(shipClass:String, shipCountry:String) {

        var returnShip:Object = new Object();

        //bummer here is we have to know what classes exist, so if any are added code must change here as well
        switch(shipCountry) {
            case "GB":

                switch(shipClass) {

                    case "GB_120_N":

                        var shipList_GB_Source:LOB_Ships_GB = new LOB_Ships_GB;
                        var shipList_GB = shipList_GB_Source.shipClasses_GB;

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_120_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_110_N":

                        var shipList_GB_Source:LOB_Ships_GB = new LOB_Ships_GB;
                        var shipList_GB = shipList_GB_Source.shipClasses_GB;

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_110_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_100_N":

                        var shipList_GB_Source:LOB_Ships_GB = new LOB_Ships_GB;
                        var shipList_GB = shipList_GB_Source.shipClasses_GB;

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_100_N;
                        break;

                    case "GB_98_N":

                        var shipList_GB_Source:LOB_Ships_GB = new LOB_Ships_GB;
                        var shipList_GB = shipList_GB_Source.shipClasses_GB;

                        returnShip = shipList_GB.GB_98_N;
                        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. You add a service parameter "installed" to each ship in `getScenarioSideOOB()` output, and assign it to `false` initially. Then, when your `scenarioMasterObj.getShip()` is called, it should set `installed` to true on the ship in OOB, and skip the matching ship if it has "installed" as true already.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work - we need every ship in the OOB, regardless of whether its class matches another. Think four Royal Navy frigates of the same exact class, all characteristics identical except for name. And it's not an issue where it's looping over again accidentally, at the time it pulls a second example of a shipClass+Country combination, it creates a new entry in shipDataSide1 or 2, but at the same time it changes the values of the previous entry with that combination to match this latest one - clearly it thinks both entries in the array are the exact same object.

Comment: Then you need to drop switch-case off `getShip()`, because your classes don't uniquely match ship instances. Instead you do a for each cycle, checking all of country, class and `installed` properties to be valid, once all are valid, change installed to true and return that ship.

Answer (score 0):

If no one has a better suggestion for handling this type of situation than the answer provided above in the update to my OP has to stand. It works, it just feels like using a sledgehammer when I know there's a precise tool for this out there somewhere.